# last-child not working nor showing in css element in devtool

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i don't understand why this is happining.
here is my code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/73ad92xh/)

as i used `first-child` and `last-child` in my CSS.
but code written in last-child is not working. also it is not showing in dev-tool style part.
it shows only `section >div div` as it should be `section >div div:last-child`.
please help me to get rid of this problem .
thank you.

Comment: @chipChoclate.py : second div should have background:#555; and its width should be 70%

Comment: "*[I] don't understand why this is [happening]*" - and without your code, neither do we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had random `;`s in your CSS. Additionally, add `box-sizing: border-box` to `section > div > div:first-child` and `section > div > div:last-child`. Next, remove any whitespace between `div`s in your HTML to align the `div`s horizontally.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/73ad92xh/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<section>
    <div><div></div><div></div></div>
</section>
```

#### CSS:

```
section {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10em;
    float: right;
    width: 65%;
}
section > div div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 10em;
}
section > div > div:first-child {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section > div > div:last-child {
    background: #555;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the "semicolon" after the curly brackets. The semicolon is used only to separate each property from one another but shouldn't be used at the end of curly brackets:

```
section > div > div:first-child{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
} /*Shouldn't have semicolon here */
section > div > div:last-child{
    background: #000;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
} /*Shouldn't have semicolon here */
```